# gdalwarp with -srcwin

Tags: gdalwarp

I am trying to cut a window (in pixels) from a geotiff file and output in a different size. gdal_translate allows that but gives no option to set resampling, while gdalwarp allows resampling while it requires the src window to be in georeferenced coords.

Is there away to get the best of both. i.e. (src in pixels and using resampling)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you apply these two steps one after the other?

Comment: I will have 100000's of files (tiling). This doubles the time which I am trying to avoid. This is an alternative and valid idea though.